# How to select both our changes and their changes during merge conflict

Tags: git, merge

Merging two branches and I want to keep all the code. I am working in atom. Here is a picture of the editor, If I click either of the 'use me' buttons the other code goes away. 
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to delete the lines containing `<<<<<<<<` and/or `========` ?

Comment: This particular issue is due to your IDE (i.e., it's specific to atom). If you were using some other merge tool it might have a similar issue, with a similarly merge-tool-specific solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't click any buttons. Just select the `>>>>` & `<<<<` & `=====` texts, and delete them. Then, sort out all the codes that you want to keep, and set your final structure, finally click SAVE.

Answer (score 2):

There was a little hamburger next to it and I could select merge ours and then theirs and it worked

Comment: This is a better answer than the accepted one.